# When should I call Director::purgeCachedData() to free memory?

Tags: android, c++, ios, memory, cocos2d-x-3.0

When I've checked the caller of `Director::purgeCachedData()` in the cocos2dx engine, no caller were found and It means nobody call this function at all !

My question is about **The situations which I may need call `purgeCachedData()` to free my memory.**    Maybe... :

**1.** `Layer::Destructors` **?**

**2.** `Layer::OnExit` **??**

**3.** For iOS: `(Void) applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:` **?**

**4.** For Android: `onLowMemory()` **???**

---

**PS:** Somewhere I read there's *no need* to call this function in cocos2dx 3.x. If this is true:

**a)** Why does this function still exist ?

**b)** Who care about unused texture and unload them ?